# How to work on jqgrid Add, edit, delete? using php

Tags: jqgrid-php

how to work on add row, edit, del the row in jqgrid? how to invoke editurl??

my code is below... jqgrid.php page.

```
 var $mygrid= jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                        url:'example.php',                                           
                        datatype: 'xml',
                        mtype: 'GET',
                        colNames:['Seq','Name', 'ID','Pass','Mail','Note'],
                        colModel :[ 
                        {name:'seq',index:'seq', width:55, resizable:false, editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10}}, 
                        {name:'name',index:'name', width:90,resizable:false, editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:false,size:10}}, 
                        {name:'id',index:'id', width:80, align:'right', editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:false,size:10}}, 
                        {name:'pass',index:'pass', width:80, align:'right', sortable:false, editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:false,size:10}}, 
                        {name:'mail',index:'mail', width:80,align:'right', sortable:false, editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:false,size:10}}, 
                        {name:'id',index:'id', width:150, sortable:false} ],                            
                        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                        rowNum:10,
                        rowList:[10,20,30,50],
                        sortname: 'seq',
                        sortorder: "Asc",
                        width: 1000,
                        height: 230,                                                                            
                        viewrecords: true,
                        multiselect: true,
                        editable: true,
                        toolbar: [true,"top"],                            
                        multikey: "ctrlKey",                           
                        editurl:'add.php',                           
                        caption: 'staff'


        });
            $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
                     edit: true,                    
                     add: true,                             
                     del: true,                     
                     search: false,                      
                     refresh:false
             })
```

});

And example.php code is

```
enter code here  <?php
                     $dbhost = 'localhost';
                     $dbuser = 'test';
                     $dbpassword = 'test';
                     $database = 'cs_test';

                     $page = $_GET['page'];
                    // get how many rows we want to have into the grid - rowNum parameter in the grid
                     $limit = $_GET['rows'];
                    // get index row - i.e. user click to sort. At first time sortname parameter -
                    // after that the index from colModel
                    $sidx = $_GET['sidx'];

                     // sorting order - at first time sortorder
                     $sord = $_GET['sord'];
                     // if we not pass at first time index use the first column for   the index or what you want
                    if(!$sidx) $sidx =1;
                    // connect to the MySQL database server
                    $db = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die("Connection Error: " . mysql_error());
                   // select the database
                   mysql_select_db($database) or die("Error conecting to db.");
                   // calculate the number of rows for the query. We need this to paging the result
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM TM_Staff");
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
                    $count = $row['count'];
                    // calculation of total pages for the query
                    if( $count > 0 ) {
                $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
                //$total_pages = 20;
                    } else {
                 $total_pages = 0;
                    }
                    if ($page > $total_pages) $page=$total_pages;
                        $start = $limit*$page - $limit;
                        if($start<0) $start = 0;
                       // the actual query for the grid data
                        $SQL = "SELECT seq,name,id,pass,mail,ins_dt from TM_Staff ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start,$limit";
                        $result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn t execute query.".mysql_error());
                       if ( stristr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"],"application/xhtml+xml") )                          {
                             header("Content-type: application/xhtml+xml;charset=utf-8");
                       } else {
                        header("Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");
                       }
                       echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
                       echo "<rows>";
                       echo "<page>".$page."</page>";
                       echo "<total>".$total_pages."</total>";
                       echo "<records>".$count."</records>";
                       // be sure to put text data in CDATA
                       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                        echo "<row id='". $row[seq]."'>";
                        echo "<cell>". $row[seq]."</cell>";
                        echo "<cell>". $row[name]."</cell>";
                        echo "<cell>". $row[id]."</cell>";
                            echo "<cell>". $row[pass]."</cell>";
                        echo "<cell>". $row[mail]."</cell>";
                        echo "<cell><![CDATA[". $row[id]."]]></cell>";
                        echo "</row>";
                        }
                        echo "</rows>";
      ?>
```

plz help me, im in trouble...

Answer (score 2):

```
var lastSel;
$(function () {

    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        colNames: ['Name', 'Address', 'Contact', 'Pan Number', 'Registration Number', 'Email Address', 'File'],
        colModel: [
        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', sortable: true, align: 'left', title: false, width: 200, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmprefix: '* ' }, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc']} },

         { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', sortable: true, title: false, align: 'left', width: 220, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmprefix: '* ' }, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc']} },

          { name: 'Contact', index: 'Contact', sortable: true, title: false, align: 'left', width: 200, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmprefix: '* ' }, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc']} },

          { name: 'PanNumber', index: 'PanNumber', sortable: true, title: false, align: 'left', width: 200, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmprefix: '* ' }, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc']} },

          { name: 'ServiceTaxRegistrationNo', index: 'ServiceTaxRegistrationNo', title: false, sortable: true, align: 'left', width: 240, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { elmprefix: '* ' }, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn', 'nc']} },

            { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', sortable: true, align: 'left', title: false, width: 190, editable: true, edittype: 'text', editrules: { required: true, email: true }, formoptions: { elmprefix: '* ' }, search: false },

              { name: 'FilePath', index: 'FilePath', sortable: false, title: false, align: 'left', editable: true, edittype: 'file', width: 190, allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
                  search: false, editoptions: {
                      enctype: "multipart/form-data"
                  }
              },
        ],
        pager: jQuery("#pager"),
        sortname: 'Name',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 25],
        sortOrder: "",
        height: 225,
        viewrecords: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        caption: "Companies",
        width: 950,
        imgpath: '/Content/themes/smoothness/images',
        url: "/Master/GetCompanies",
        editurl: "/Master/PerformCompanyCRUDAction",
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "GET",
        onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol, aData) {
            if (rowid && rowid !== lastSel) {
                if (lastSel) {
                    $("#" + lastSel).removeClass('state-active');
                    $("#" + lastSel).addClass('ui-widget-content');
                }
                $("#" + rowid).removeClass('ui-widget-content');
                $("#" + rowid).addClass('state-active');
                lastSel = rowid;
            }
        }

    });

    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
     { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true },
            { closeOnEscape: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true, modal: true,
                beforeShowForm: function (formid) {
                    $("#pData, #nData").hide();
                },
                onInitializeForm: function (formid) {

                    $(formid).attr('method', 'POST');
                    $(formid).attr('action', '');
                    $(formid).attr('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
                },
                test: function () {

                    var filenam = $("#FilePath").val();
                },
                afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                    $.ajaxFileUpload({
                        url: '/Master/CompanyFileUpload?CompanyId=' + postdata.id,
                        secureuri: false,
                        data: postdata,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
                        processData: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        fileElementId: 'FilePath',
                        dataType: 'json',

                        success: function (data, status) {
                            // $('#notificationDiv').text("Bank Updated Successfully!");
                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                },
                closeAfterEdit: true, left: 200, top: 50, width: 500,

                afterShowForm: function (formid) {
                    $('#Contact').numeric({ allow: "," });
                },
                afterComplete: function (response, postdata, formid) {

                    if (response.responseText == "true") {

                        $("#notificationDivSuccess").delay(0).fadeIn("slow");
                        $('#notificationDivSuccess').text("Record Updated Successfully!");
                        $("#notificationDivSuccess").delay(2500).fadeOut("slow");
                        $('#notificationDivFail').text("");
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#notificationDivFail").delay(0).fadeIn("slow");
                        $('#notificationDivFail').text("Record Already Exist!");
                        $("#notificationDivFail").delay(2500).fadeOut("slow");
                        $('#notificationDivSuccess').text("");
                    }
                }
            },
            { closeOnEscape: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                closeAfterAdd: true, left: 200, top: 50, width: 500,
                onInitializeForm: function (formid) {

                    $(formid).attr('method', 'POST');
                    $(formid).attr('action', '');
                    $(formid).attr('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
                },

                afterShowForm: function (formid) {
                    $('#Contact').numeric({ allow: "," });
                },

                afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                    //                    var data = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                    //                    bid = data.id;
                    //                    pageNo = data.page;
                    //debugger;
                    var Id = response.responseText;

                    $.ajaxFileUpload({
                        url: '/Master/CompanyFileUpload?CompanyId=' + Id,
                        secureuri: false,
                        data: postdata,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
                        processData: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        fileElementId: 'FilePath',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data, status) {
                            // $('#notificationDiv').text("Bank Added Successfully!");
                        }
                    });
                    return true;
                }
                ,
                afterComplete: function (response, postdata, formid) {

                    if (response.responseText != "") {
                        if (response.responseText == "false") {
                            $("#notificationDivFail").delay(0).fadeIn("slow");
                            $('#notificationDivFail').text("Record Already Exist!");
                            $("#notificationDivFail").delay(2500).fadeOut("slow");
                            $('#notificationDivSuccess').text("");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#notificationDivSuccess").delay(0).fadeIn("slow");
                            $('#notificationDivSuccess').text("New Record Added Successfully!");
                            $("#notificationDivSuccess").delay(2500).fadeOut("slow");
                            $('#notificationDivFail').text("");
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                    }
                }
            },
            { closeOnEscape: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true, left: 300, top: 80, width: 220,
                afterComplete: function (response, postdata, formid) {
                    if (response.responseText == "true") {
                        $("#notificationDivSuccess").delay(0).fadeIn("slow");
                        $('#notificationDivSuccess').text("Record Deleted Successfully!");
                        $("#notificationDivSuccess").delay(2500).fadeOut("slow");
                        $('#notificationDivFail').text("");
                    }
                    else {

                        $("#notificationDivFail").delay(0).fadeIn("slow");
                        $('#notificationDivFail').text("The selected record can not be deleted, Please delete associated record first");
                        $("#notificationDivFail").delay(2500).fadeOut("slow");
                        $('#notificationDivSuccess').text("");
                    }
                }
            },
            { closeAfterSearch: true, closeOnEscape: true, left: 200, top: 50, enableClear: true,
                onClose: function () {
                    var postdata = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
                    postdata._search = false;
                    postdata.searchString = "";
                    $("#grid").trigger('reloadGrid');
                    return true;
                }

            });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In edit.php you have to put it like this:

```
if($_POST['oper']=='add')
 {
    ... ... ...
 }
else if($_POST['oper']=='edit')
 {
    ... ... ...
 }
else if($_POST['oper']=='del')
 {
    ... ... ...
 }
```

If you want to see what you are getting, use: `print_r($_REQUEST);`

Answer (score 0):

```
           var $mygrid= jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                    url:'example.php',
                    editurl: 'edit.php',                                           
                    datatype: 'xml',
                    mtype: 'GET',
                    colNames:['Seq','Name', 'ID','Pass','Mail','Note'],
                    colModel :[ 
                    {name:'seq',index:'seq', width:55, resizable:false, editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:true,size:10}}, 
                    {name:'name',index:'name', width:90,resizable:false, editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:false,size:10}}, 
                    {name:'id',index:'id', width:80, align:'right', editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:false,size:10}}, 
                    {name:'pass',index:'pass', width:80, align:'right', sortable:false, editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:false,size:10}}, 
                    {name:'mail',index:'mail', width:80,align:'right', sortable:false, editable:true, editoptions:{readonly:false,size:10}}, 
                    {name:'id',index:'id', width:150, sortable:false} ],                            
                    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
                    rowNum:10,
                    rowList:[10,20,30,50],
                    sortname: 'seq',
                    sortorder: "Asc",
                    width: 1000,
                    height: 230,                                                                            
                    viewrecords: true,
                    multiselect: true,
                    editable: true,
                    toolbar: [true,"top"],                            
                    multikey: "ctrlKey",                           
                    caption: 'staff'


    });
        $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
                 edit: true,                    
                 add: true,                             
                 del: true,                     
                 search: false,                      
                 refresh:false
         })
```

In edit.php

```
 if($_GET['oper']=='add')
 {
    ... ... ...
 }
 if($_GET['oper']=='edit')
 {
    ... ... ...
 }
 if($_GET['oper']=='del')
 {
    ... ... ...
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I really like the idea of PHPjq however the code they are "selling" does not have any of the best practices to prevent SQL injection. so buy their code and add the proper sql escape wrappers or write your own .... be safe not lazy.

Comment: Are you associated with PHPjq?