# How to use edit function in Jqgrid

Tags: jsp, jqgrid, row, edit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to work on jqgrid Add, edit, delete? using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162947/how-to-work-on-jqgrid-add-edit-delete-using-php)

I use Jqgrid to describe my data tables effectively and easily.

As you know, Jqgrid API includes edit function.

I think it is very nice.

But I'm in trouble...

All examples are for PHP language users, while I use JSP language.

My point is what means editurl valuable.

```
                multiselect: false,
                paging: true,
                rowNum:10,
                rowList:[10,20,30],
                pager: $("#page"),
                loadonce:true,
        **editurl: 'edit.jsp',** // what is this valuable?
                caption: "Test Grid"
```

Example in demo site explains it is just dummy site.

How am I make 'editurl' page?

Please give me a example for JSP.